# Troublesome regex matching

Tags: regex

I was hoping some Regex-experts out there could help me with this one. I have some examples that I would like to match:

```
fooenvwesteucontainerregistry.azurecr.io
http://healthcheck-env-westeu-container.westeurope.azurecontainer.io
https://foo-env2-westeu-app-myapp.azurewebsites.net
https://foo-io9-westeu-app-myapp.azurewebsites.net
http://healthcheck-env-westeu-container.westeurope.azurecontainer.io
```

I would like to have a regex that matches the "env", "env2", and "io9". As I see it the "westeu" is sort of the anchor and I tried to match based on that.
The closest I got was using `(?<=foo)(-?)(\w+)(-?)(westeu)` but it doesn't work in the instances where "foo" doesn't appear.

https://regex101.com/r/xcIfbY/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Try `(?:foo)?-?(\w+)-?westeu`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RopvIt/2)

Comment: if you want your regex to work in instances where "foo" doesn't appear, juste remove the lookbehind `(?<=foo)` in your regex.

Comment: @iElden If the lookbehind is removed, the `foo` might get included in Group 1 captured substring, and OP needs to exclude it. Hence, the `foo` pattern should be just enclosed with an optional group so that if there is `foo`, it would get consumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:foo)?-?(\w+)-?westeu
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RopvIt/2) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3Afoo)%3F-%3F(%5Cw%2B)-%3Fwesteu):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?:foo)?` - an optional sbubstring `foo`
- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more letters, digits, `_`
- `-?westeu` - an optional `-` and then `westeu`